# Why does Java stream map reduce count my result twice?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, reduce

I have this code a:

```
        ComparisonResults comparisonResults = requestsList
                .stream()
                .map(item -> getResponse(item))
                .map(item -> compareToBl(item))
                .reduce(new ComparisonResults(), (result1, result2) ->
                {
                     result1.addSingleResult(result2);
                 //   return result1;
                    return new ComparisonResults(result1);
                });
```

and this code b:

```
        ComparisonResults comparisonResults = requestsList
                .parallelStream()
                .map(item -> getResponse(item))
                .map(item -> compareToBl(item))
                .reduce(new ComparisonResults(), (result1, result2) ->
                {
                     result1.addSingleResult(result2);
                 //   return result1;
                    return new ComparisonResults(result1);
                });
```

All I do is to create response objects, then transform them to comaprisonResult objects and to reduce them to one comaprisonResult.

code `a` shows an int class member `comparisonResults.num_of_sub_responses==5` which is correct

code `b` shows an int class member `comparisonResults.num_of_sub_responses==10` which is double the correct result.

java 8 reduce should be thread safe, right?

am i missing anything?

`getResponse` and `compareToBl` are thread safe

Comment: Show the code for `ComparisonResult`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your are mutating an incoming object in `reduce`. This is wrong. It doesn’t help that you are creating a new object *after* modifying the incoming object.

What you want to do, is

```
.collect(ComparisonResults::new, ComparisonResults::addSingleResult,
         (a,b)->/* code to merge two ComparisonResults instances*/);
```

If the result of `.map(item -> compareToBl(item))` is `ComparisonResults` or, in other words, `addSingleResult` merges two `ComparisonResults` instances, you can use `ComparisonResults::addSingleResult` as merge function, though it’s name is a bit misleading then.

You should carefully read the [“Reduction” chapter of the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#Reduction) and its follow-up, “Mutable reduction”.

Answer (score 2):

The reduce operation `reduce(identity, operator)` relies on two important assumptions about the arguments you pass it.

1. The first parameter is an *identity*. That is, when you use the reducing operator between any item and the given `identity`, you get the original item.
2. The operator is associative.

These two assumptions are very important when working with a parallel stream, because in general, what it does is:

- Give each thread a slice of the stream
- Each thread starts with the identity, and accumulates a result using the elements in the stream:

  ```
  result = identity op element1 op element2 op element3 ...
  ```
- Then the results from different threads are combined together using the operator:

  ```
  grand result = result1 op result2 op result3
  ```

So, suppose you were summing numbers, it breaks an operation like `5 + 4 + 3 + 20` into `( 0 + 5 + 4 ) + ( 0 + 3 + 20 )`. Which works if, and only if, the above assumptions are true. (0 is the identity for addition, addition is associative).

But by mutating the first operand inside your operator, it means that you are actually mutating the *identity* object. So it cannot be considered an *identity* anymore. That is `op(identity,result)` does not give you the same value as `result` itself.

If the operator is not associative, problems will turn up in the "grand result" stage.