# Java Stream reduce unexplained behaviour

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, reduce

Can anyone please point me in the right direction as I cannot understand the issue.

I am executing following method.

```
private static void reduce_parallelStream() {
    List<String> vals = Arrays.asList("a", "b");

    List<String> join = vals.parallelStream().reduce(new ArrayList<String>(),
            (List<String> l, String v) -> {

                l.add(v);

                return l;
            }, (a, b) -> {                   
                a.addAll(b);
                return a;
            }

    );

   System.out.println(join);

}
```

It prints

> [null, a, null, a]

I cannot understand why does it put two null in the resultant list. I expected the answer to be

> [a, b]

as it is a parallel stream so the first parameter to reduce

> new ArrayList()

would probably be called twice for each input value a and b.

Then the accumulator function would probably be called twice as it is a parallelStream and pass each input "a and b" in each call along with the lists provided by seeded value. So a is added to list 1 and b is added to list 2 (or vice versa). Afterwards the combinator will combine both lists but it doesn't happen.

Interestingly, if I put a print statement inside my accumulator to print the value of input, the output changes. So following

```
private static void reduce_parallelStream() {
    List<String> vals = Arrays.asList("a", "b");

    List<String> join = vals.parallelStream().reduce(new ArrayList<String>(),
            (List<String> l, String v) -> {
                System.out.printf("l is %s", l);
                l.add(v);
                System.out.printf("l is %s", l);
                return l;
            }, (a, b) -> {
                a.addAll(b);
                return a;
            }

    );

   System.out.println(join);

}
```

results in this output

> l is []l is [b]l is [b, a]l is [b, a]**[b, a, b, a]**

Can anyone please explain.

Comment: ArrayList is not a threadsafe collection, so any concurrent call may result in unexpected behaviour. On the other hand, when using System.out.println, there is a hidden synchronization mechanism in place. What happens when you use a [synchronized list](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#synchronizedList(java.util.List))?

Comment: There is an interesting explanation on [coderanch](https://coderanch.com/t/678797/java/explanation-stream-reduce-parallelStream-reduce)

Comment: Like in [Why does Java stream map reduce count my result twice?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33375335/2711488) and likely some other examples of wrong use of `reduce`. Reading [the package documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#Reduction) (both sections, “Reduction operations” and “Mutable reduction”) may also help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be using `Collections.synchronizedList()` when working with `parallelStream()`. Because `ArrayList` is not threadsafe and you get unexpected behavior when accessing it concurrently, like you're doing it with `parallelStream()`.

I have modified your code and now it's working correctly:

```
private static void reduce_parallelStream() {
    List<String> vals = Arrays.asList("a", "b");

    // Use Synchronized List when with parallelStream()
    List<String> join = vals.parallelStream().reduce(Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<>()),
            (l, v) -> {
                l.add(v);
                return l;
            }, (a, b) -> a // don't use addAll() here to multiplicate the output like [a, b, a, b]
    );
    System.out.println(join);
}
```

**Output:**

Sometimes you'll get this output:

```
[a, b]
```

And sometimes this one:

```
[b, a]
```

Reason for this is that it's a `parallelStream()` so you can't be sure about the order of execution.

Answer (score 3):

> as it is a parallel stream so the first parameter to reduce `new ArrayList()`
>   would probably be called twice for each input value a and b.

That's where you are wrong. The first parameter is a single `ArrayList` instance, **not** a lambda expression can produce multiple `ArrayList` instances.

Therefore, the entire reduction operates on a single `ArrayList` instance. When multiple threads modify that `ArrayList` in parallel, the results may change in each execution.

Your `combiner` actually adds all the elements of a `List` to the same `List`.

You can obtain the expected `[a,b]` output if both the `accumulator` and `combiner` functions will produce a new `ArrayList` instead of mutating their input `ArrayList`:

```
List<String> join = vals.parallelStream().reduce(
     new ArrayList<String>(),
        (List<String> l, String v) -> {
            List<String> cl = new ArrayList<>(l);
            cl.add(v);
            return cl;
        }, (a, b) -> {
            List<String> ca = new ArrayList<>(a);
            ca.addAll(b);
            return ca;
        }
);
```

That said, you shouldn't be using `reduce` at all. `collect` is the correct way to perform a mutable reduction:

```
List<String> join = vals.parallelStream()
                        .collect(ArrayList::new,ArrayList::add,ArrayList::addAll);
```

As you can see, here, unlike in `reduce`, the first parameter you pass is a `Supplier<ArrayList<String>>`, which can be used to generate as many intermediate `ArrayList` instances as necessary.

Comment: …and `.collect(ArrayList::new,ArrayList::add,ArrayList::addAll)` is a re-implementation of `.collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new))`, resp. `.collect(Collectors.toList())` if we do not care about the returned list’s actual type.

Answer (score 0):

It is rather simple, the first argument is the *identity* or I would say *zero* to start with. For `parallelStream usage` this value is *reused*. That means concurrency problems (the null from an add) and duplicates.

This can be patched by:

```
    final ArrayList<String> zero = new ArrayList<>();
    List<String> join = vals.parallelStream().reduce(zero,
            (List<String> l, String v) -> {
                if (l == zero) {
                    l = new ArrayList<>();
                }
                l.add(v);
                return l;
            }, (a, b) -> {
                // See comment of Holger:
                if (a == zero) return b;
                if (b == zero) return a;

                a.addAll(b);
                return a;
            }
    );
```

Safe.

You might wonder why `reduce` has no overload for an identity providing function.
The reason is that `collect` should have been used here.

Comment: There is no guaranty that the combiner does not get an identity value. So you have to perform `if (a == zero)  a = new ArrayList<>();` there as well. It’s better to spot errors early, so using `final List<String> zero = Collections.emptyList();` is preferable. And perhaps, there are more problems which don’t see at the moment. Generally, don’t use an API against its intention…

Comment: @Holger I doubt that all the combiner calls could get the identity more than once, and I did not previously abuse the identity. My last line is in total agreement with you; I did not give a collect solution as Eran gave one. You are right for zero: should at least be unmodifiable.

Comment: Just try with `IntStream.range(0, 0x10001).filter(i -> Integer.highestOneBit(i)==i) .parallel().mapToObj(String::valueOf)`